# Cannot access external storage on some Firebase devices

Tags: android, firebase, android-external-storage

I have an Android app (developed under Xamarin.Android) which works fine when I test it locally on both emulators and physical devices.  However, it fails on two physical devices (Moto G4, API 23, and Huawei Mate 9, API 24) when it goes through automatic testing on the Google Play Console.  The problem arises when trying to create a log file in external storage.  I have been running various tests under Firebase on the Moto G4, but cannot work out where the problem lies.  I would be really grateful for at least one more pair of eyes on what I’m doing.

I check `Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageState`, which returns “`MediaMounted`”.  I then use `GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads)` to work out where to create my log file.  This returns “`/storage/emulated/0/Download`”.  I next check that read/write permission has been granted.  `ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Android.Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage)` and `ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Android.Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage)` both return `Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted`. (In AndroidManifest.xml, I list `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`.)

At this point, I have established (I think) that the directory exists and that I have permission to write to it, so I try to create my log file, `/storage/emulated/0/Download/LogFile.txt`.  This works fine locally, on both emulators and physical devices.  It also works on most of the devices that the Google Console test puts to test.  However, on the Moto G4 (physical device), file creation fails with the error “Could not find part of the path”.

I have also tried writing to `DirectoryDocuments` instead of `DirectoryDownloads`, which the Android documentation tells me is the “standard directory in which to place documents that have been created by the user”.  The path returned for this is `/storage/emulated/0/documents`.  When I try to write to that directory, it fails saying that the directory does not exist (which I believe is true).
Enumerating the contents of the Download directory, I noticed that there is a “Documents” directory inside the Download directory, i.e. `/storage/emulated/0/Download/Documents`.  Writing to this directory again gives me the error “could not find part of the path”, same as writing to the `Download` directory itself.

My app absolutely has to store files somewhere (not just the log file).  It is also important that the user can copy these files to/from the device, and I don’t want the files to be deleted, even if the app is uninstalled.  For these reasons, I believe that external storage is the right (only) place for them.

I am at a loss to know what to try next.  (I am wondering now whether there is actually an issue with the device, like a disk format issue.)  If anyone has any suggestions on where to go from here, I would be really grateful! Extensive searches have not thrown up anything that I'm doing wrong, or any suggestion that the directory structure may be different on a Moto G4.

Comment: `Cannot access external storage on some Firebase devices` ?? A FireBase device? What's that? Andoid device?

Comment: Please post your code readable. All code in one code block.

Comment: Hello blackapps, just in case you are actually trying to be helpful: I mean "a physical device running as part of Firebase Test Lab", but that would have made for a very long heading. And, yes, it's an Android app and, therefore, running on an Android device; or at least intended for running on an Android device ;-)